# Q: I'm trying to give the same styles on .class::before and .class::after but I can't see the result on live server

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list(ol) on my project and I wanna add an pseudo elements (::before,::after),
If I write ::before and ::after separately its accepting whatever style I gave and its appearing on server, otherwise, its not showing up the result on live server. Here below I left my code and live server pics... Sorry, my explanation will not be clear but I uploaded two pictures for more understanding.

[when I gave 1 to the content its working[][1]][but it is not working when I wrote ::before and ::after in one class 2]

Here is my code:

```
.cinema-seats__list:first-child::before
.cinema-seats__list:first-child::after {
  content: "1";
}
```

> if I delete .cinema-seats__list:first-child::after this part its gonna work

```
.cinema-seats__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between ;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. It would be hard to help you without seeing your code. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved (in text form!) and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.cinema-seats__list:first-child::before,
.cinema-seats__list:first-child::after {
      content: "1";
    }

You have to put coma(,) seperate line just like above code.
```